# How do I make sure that a String contains only Date(2020-07-14) or DateTime both like(2020-07-14T05:23:51.711Z) in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I'm writing an API in which user can pass only date(2020-07-14) or DateTime both like this "2020-07-14T05:23:51.711Z" in a variable start_date as shown below. How do I make sure that user has passed only date or DateTime both?

```
Input1: start_date = "2020-07-14T05:23:51.711Z"
output1: contains date and time both

Input2: start_date = "2020-07-14"
output2: contains only Date

Input3: start_date = "2020-07-14Tsome_random_string"
output3: not a proper DateTime format

Input4: start_date = "some_random_string"
output4: not a proper DateTime format
```

I have checked DateTime API's in ruby doesn't find anything specific.

Comment: https://makandracards.com/makandra/57531-rails-use-date-strptime-to-parse-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def valid_date?(str)
    date = Date.xmlschema(str)
    if(str.include? 'T')
        return 'Contains both Date & Time'
    end
    return 'Contains Date only'
rescue => e
    return 'Not a valid Date or DateTime'
end
```